Books on mathematical constructions
I’m looking for suggestions and recommendations for books that focus on constructions in mathematics, or at least have exercises which focus on construction-based proofs.
In particular, I seem to struggle with formulating proofs that entail a construction, so I’m looking for a resource which discusses approaching this feat, or at least has several such problems for practice.
For example, the proof of the iteration theorem involves constructing n-admissible functions, which seemed very left-field to me (at least, to conjure up on my own as a proof attempt before checking the published proof). Thanks in advance! Any other recommendations outside of resource recommendations will also be well-taken!
Edit: I should add this based on the first couple responses. I am familiar with proofs and proof-writing, it’s simply that the books that are being mentioned don’t seem to provide adequate preparation for encountering any of the substantial proofs that entail constructions (it may be an extreme example, but consider the proof of constructing the reals from the rationals, for instance). I’d just like a resource that would help me perhaps sketch out such a proof on my own- or even a bit- before seeing it.

Have you taken a look at Hammack's "Book of Proofs"?
https://richardhammack.github.io/BookOfProof/

Consider How to Solve It by Polya

The two most popular recommendations for self-study are probably Hammock's Book of Proof and How to Prove it by Velleman. I have only personally been through the former, but have heard countless great things about Velleman's.
For something more specific to your question (regarding constructions), I can recommend Discrete Mathematical Structures by Bernard Kolman. This is available for free online, as is Book of Proof which is free and open source if that interests you.

Besides the $\textit{Book of Proof}$, which is the most famous recommendation, I would recommend two other references, the first one being the most direct to the point of the proof itself, and the second one being the one with the most amount of "different" math in terms of content itself.

$\textit{How to Read and Do Proofs}$, by Daniel Solow. This is a fairly quick one to complete, but I think it has an excellent reading

$\textit{Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics}$, by G. Chartrand, A. Polimeni and P. Zhang. To me, this one is all about its content. The advantage of this book is that it is published by Pearson, so all the exercises are available, with their commented solutions, and many of them are on the construction side that you have mentioned.


